# Can't get Java to work in Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, installation

I've been trying to install java on vs code for a couple hours now and I can't seem to get it to work. I've already downloaded all the extensions necessary and I've downloaded the coding pack from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java for windows (I'm on windows 11). According to multiple tutorials, this is all I should have to do, but when I make a test.java file, the "run java" does nothing and "run code" gives me an error.

[image: code]

and this is the output when I click that run button in the top right: [image: output]

Does anybody have any suggestions? the coding pack was supposed to come with a jdk, its working for everybody else so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you don't have correctly installed `java sdk` on your system.

Try to check `java sdk` installation with following commands:

```
java --version
javac --version
```

In case you don't see reasonable output, try to install `java sdk`,
go to the Java [Downloads](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk17-windows) section of the Oracle website, and download the Installer from there.

Comment: The output is working fine for both of those though. Is it not on my path? I really don't understand whats going on

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are following the documentation? It looks like you didn't download the official Java extension pack, but used **Code Runner** to run the code.

Please download the [Java extension package](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack) and use `Run Java` or `Run` to run the code.

[image]

[Getting Started with Java in VS Code.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial)